# Not show node count view in drupal 7

Tags: 7, nodes

I have installed node count view module and configured it.

But it's not showing me anything anywhere in my site. And I am not getting the setting of node count view.

Any suggestions about where I can see the 'node counts'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit `admin/config/system/statistics` and enable the following settings.

[image]

These are the standard options I use for showing the node count. They some to work well in my case.

Comment: you have given me another module settings that is statics count module i installed that module and its working. thankyou.

Comment: It was not clear from your question. Glad it helped anyways. If you found this useful you can upvote this answer/ mark it as accepted so that it will help others. @rahullodhi

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using the [Node view count](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeviewcount) module (there doesn't seem to be a 'Node count view' module ...). And also that you used `admin/config/content/count-views` to configure the module, i.e. to select the node types and user roles for which to count node view.

There doesn't seem to be lot (any?) of documentation about this module available. Not a readme.txt, no "Read documentation" link on the project pages, etc. The best 'documentation' that I have been able to find so far is what is written in [issue 2123609](https://www.drupal.org/node/2123609#comment-8017535). Here is a summary of it:

- The module integrates with the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module.
- A few views are included/shipped with the module (enable them as apprpriate).
- A admin user can see statistics by visiting `/admin/config/content/node-views-count-statistics`.

Potentially something that you might want to review/check also, is what is written in [issue 2317873](https://www.drupal.org/node/2317873) ... Therefor consider editing your question related to the theme you're using, and/or if you're using the [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) module ... (that would explain why you don't see anything ...).